# Can I mute a single application or an ActiveX control in it?

Tags: .net, winapi, activex, flash

I have a Flash Player ActiveX control in my .NET application. I would like to mute it (if possible, only the Flash control itself, but muting the whole application is a good compromise). Muting the whole system is not viable.

Comment: Windows Vista+ allows individual applications to be muted. Either use the old "master volume" which Windows will map to just your application, or the new [Core Audio API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370784(v=vs.85).aspx). Pre Vista and you'll need to tell the control to shut itself up.

Comment: How can I tell it to do so? I couldn't find an API for it, nor a COM interface it exposes that does it. [These guys](http://f-in-box.com/) do it somehow.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been "Try to find a way to..." I was answering part of the question that I could, leaving the control specific bit to someone else :)